# Adsense: resource not found: error 400(OK)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, adsense

I have a strange problem with some adblocks on my website. 
On almost all my content pages, I have placed 3 Adsense blocks per page.
When I visit one of these pages in Chrome, there are always 2 blocks loaded, and the third stays empty. When I look in the console in Chrome, I see the following error:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (OK)"

This problem only occurs in Chrome, in Firefox and IE all three blocks are loaded as they should. The strange thing is, that if I refresh the page, all 3 ads are loaded properly. When you go directly to the link of one of the content pages, all ads are also loaded properly (try it yourself: www.gratiseredivisiekijken.nl/live-voetbal-kijken.html and you'll see three blocks). The problem only occurs when you are navigating to a content page trough my site via the menu.

I've already tried a few things: replacing all my responsive ads with 'normal' ads but it didn't fix the problem. I've also removed unnecessary 'adsbygoogle.js' references but without success.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?